# Open file with subl on Windows 10 Bash

Tags: windows-10, bash, sublime-text-3

I just installed Bash On Ubuntu for Windows 10 and been trying to open files with an alias. The alias I created is like this:

`alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe" $1 &'`

But I get the following error when I try to open a file:

```
[1] 276
bash: /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe: No such file or directory
test.txt: command not found
[1]+  Exit 127                "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe" $1
```

Anyone have experience with opening files and directories with sublime in the new bash for windows 10?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use both the double quotes and the backslashes to escape the spaces. Either surround the program path in quotes **OR** escape the spaces with backslashes, but don't do both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"'
```

Comment: Can you expand on what this command does and why you think it will work?